# C++ Thread - Multithreading: Infinite run without error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a Program which basically reads a File with a lot of lines.
Each line has to be processed separately. I'm using the NLP tool [spaCy](https://github.com/d99kris/spacy-cpp) in form of a wrapper library in my C++ project and every thing works fine until I use Threads.

Here is what I do:

1. I generate a new spaCy object for each thread. With that spaCy object I generate nlp object with is later used to parse a text and generate a "doc".

```
    Pipeline::Pipeline(const uint &size,
                   std::string input_file_path,
                   std::string output_file_name) :
        input_file_path_(std::move(input_file_path)),
        output_file_name_(std::move((output_file_name))) {

        for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Spacy::Spacy spacy;
            nlp_queue_.push(spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"));
            spacy_vector_.push_back(spacy);
        }
    }
```

2. I start my pipeline and start reading the file.
   To keep it simple I added the dummy function "TestDoc" which
   will be called in a new thread and it also will be joined right after:

```
    void Pipeline::RunPipeline() {
        std::ifstream jFile(input_file_path_);
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        while (getline(jFile, line)) {
            std::thread thread (&TestDoc,
                            this,
                            line);
            thread.join();
        }
    }
```

3. Here is the TestGetDoc and GetDoc function:

```
    void Pipeline::TestGetDoc() {
        Spacy::Doc doc = Pipeline::GetDoc("Something to test if it works");
    }

    Spacy::Doc Pipeline::GetDoc(const std::string &text) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> queue_lock(queue_mutex_);
        while(nlp_queue_.empty()) queue_condition_.wait(queue_lock);
        Spacy::Nlp nlp = nlp_queue_.front();
        nlp_queue_.pop();
        queue_lock.unlock();
        Spacy::Spacy spacy = spacy_vector_[0];
        Spacy::Doc doc = nlp.parse(text); // << HERE IT RUNS INTO PROBLEMS
        queue_lock.lock();
        nlp_queue_.push(nlp);
        queue_condition_.notify_one();
        return doc;
    }
```

Now what happens is, that if I run this without creating a Thread is works without any problem. But if I do it with thread, it runs until the position where I added a comment in GetDoc. It starts the parsing Process but never comes back. I tried a lot but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is also the case if I just have one single thread.

Does anyone of you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's `TestDoc` and how, if at all, is it related to `TestGetDoc`?

Comment: Aside: creating and destroying threads in a loop *per line* is not a great design architecturally. Better to have a pool of threads that pull work from a queue and execute it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Spacy`. Upon cursory examination, it appears to be a wrapper around a Python library, relying on CPython. CPython in turn appears to require [some explicit management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) before it can be used from multiple threads. You can't just pass CPython objects across threads willy-nilly.

Comment: Besides, it appears that Python interpreter [is effectively single-threaded](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) - everything runs under one global lock. Which means you likely won't see any benefit from running multiple threads, even if you manage to get it to work.